# How to create random data efficiently

Tags: c#, arrays, random

I was creating random byte arrays to test some transport layer. I used to transport data created like this

```
 public byte[] Read(Data data) {
  var rnd = new Random();
  int size = data.ChunkSize;

  byte[] array = new byte[size];
  rnd.NextBytes(array);
  return array;
}
```

Because `Read()` is called many times, and creating a new byte array every time and filling it with random data could be slow, I wanted to come up with a solution, which doesn't use `rnd.NextBytes` in every call.

So I came up with a Class, which holds a static random array and reads from it. When it comes to the end of that array, it will start from the beginning again:

```
public class MyBuffer
{
private static readonly Random SRandom = new Random();

private readonly byte[] buffer = new byte[5000000]; // 5mb array with random data to read from
private int currentStart;

public MyBuffer()
{
  SRandom.NextBytes(buffer);
}

public IEnumerable<byte> Latest(int amountOfBytes)
{
  return FetchItems(amountOfBytes).ToArray();
}

private IEnumerable<byte> FetchItems(int amountOfBytes)
{
  IEnumerable<byte> fetchedItems = Enumerable.Empty<byte>();
  int total = 0;

  while (total < amountOfBytes)
  {
    int min = Math.Min(amountOfBytes, buffer.Length - currentStart);
    fetchedItems = fetchedItems.Concat(FetchItems(currentStart, min));

    total += min;
    currentStart += min;
    currentStart = currentStart % buffer.Length;
  }

  return fetchedItems;
}
private IEnumerable<byte> FetchItems(int start, int end)
{
  for (int i = start; i < end; i++)
  {
    yield return buffer[i];
  }
}
}
```

and the calling code looks like this:

```
private static readonly MyBuffer SBuffer = new MyBuffer();
private static byte[] array = new byte[0];

public byte[] Read(Data data) {

  int size = data.ChunkSize;

  if (array.Length != size)
  {
    array = new byte[size];
  }

  Array.Copy(SBuffer.Latest(size).ToArray(), array, size);
  return array;
}
```

But this turns out to be even slower (way slower) than my first attempt, and I can't really see why. Anyone can tell me where my code is inefficient or come up with any other efficient solution to my problem?

Thanks

Comment: Did you actually have performance problems with Random `NextBytes`? If so, how much faster does it have to be? Also, move your `Random` instantiation outside of the method.

Comment: @FCin To clarify: Im creating this random data on a server and sending it via ethernet to the client. I want to benchmark the our transportation layer and thus make sure the creating and filling of the array is not my bottleneck when measuring data transmission.

Comment: Creating random bytes is extremely quick...Much quicker than messing around copying chunks of arrays around and trying to concat them.

Comment: @MatthewWatson I just created a little console app which creates a new byte array and fills it with random data (my first approach) and it takes 18 seconds on my server to create 10 arrays of 90mb size each.

Comment: Why do you need so much of pseudorandom numbers and can't you reuse the file or at least just modify a little bit of the file?

Comment: @FCin I'm not sure if I can. I wanted to make sure my code won't be optimized and/or no cashing mechanism will increase the speed in my test.

Comment: **Use a profiler**.  Stop guessing where the time is being spent and use science to know where it is being spent.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care too much about the quality of the random data you can write your own RNG that uses simple linear congruential generation:

```
public static int FillWithRandomData(int seed, byte[] array)
{
    unchecked
    {
        int n = seed * 134775813 + 1;

        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; ++i)
        {
            array[i] = (byte) n;
            n = 2147483629 * n + 2147483587;
        }

        return n;
    }
}
```

This is pretty quick, although it doesn't have a very long period - but I think it would suffice for your purposes.

If you time this, make sure you time a release build not a debug build.

It is about seven times faster than using `Random.NextBytes()` when I time it.

You can use `Random` to create a seed when you call it, or just pass the return value from the previous call.

Here's my full test app:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace Demo
{
    public class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            byte[] data = new byte[90 * 1024 * 1024];

            Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();

            int seed = (int) DateTime.Now.Ticks;

            for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
                seed = FillWithRandomData(seed, data);

            Console.WriteLine(sw.Elapsed);
        }

        public static int FillWithRandomData(int seed, byte[] array)
        {
            unchecked
            {
                int n = seed * 134775813 + 1;

                for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; ++i)
                {
                    array[i] = (byte) n;
                    n = 2147483629 * n + 2147483587;
                }

                return n;
            }
        }
    }
}
```